# How can i do core data migration?

Tags: core-data, core-data-migration

I have an old core data version with `Allows external storage` in Binary data. And i have created a new one where `Allows external storage` was unchecked. When i tried to launch my app i got an error:

Unresolved error

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134140 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (Cocoa error 134140.)" UserInfo=0xbd5cd20 {reason=Can't
>   find or automatically infer mapping model for migration,
>   destinationModel=...

Then I have created a new file in my project - `Model.xcmappingmodel`. I have selected source data model and target data model.

After that i see

> NSPersistentStoreCoordinator error: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator
>   _coordinator_you_never_successfully_opened_the_database_schema_mismatch

Answer (score 0):

For future context ... writing to CoreData's external storage is broken as of iOS 12. My solution was based off [Drew McCormack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152526/drew-mccormack)'s comments on Twitter.

It's worth noting that only writing is broken, reading remains functional.

Create a new property eg `«original property name»Internal` with the same type but with `Allows external storage` box **unchecked**.

You now have two options:

- Migrate everything on initial startup of the app - ie fetch all objects with a predicate like this `«original property name»Internal == NULL && «original property name» != NULL` and move the data across (I did this).
- Migrate on the fly ie use the two properties in parallel but only write to `«original property name»Internal` (while `nil`ing `«original property name»`)

Worth noting one last time that your customer's data is safe until they update it. Tred carefully but you should be fine.